# How to match text efficiently between two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-polars

I have some text data：
`data1`

| id | comment | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_A | good | a file name |
| user_B | a better way is… | is there some good sugg？ |
| user_C | a another way is… | is there some good sugg？ |
| user_C | I have been using Pandas for a long time, so I… | a book |

You can use

```py
pd.read_clipboard()
```

to replicate it.

`data2`

| userid | title |
| --- | --- |
| user_X | is there some good sugg？ |
| user_Y | a great idea… |
| user_Z | a file name |
| user_W | a book |

desired output

| uid | comment | title | uid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_A | good | a file name | user_Z |
| user_B | a better way is… | is there some good sugg？ | user_X |
| user_C | a another way is… | is there some good sugg？ | user_X |
| user_C | I have been using Pandas for a long time, so I… | a book | user_W |

An easy way is to merge on `title`
In `pandas` :

```py
dataall = pd.merge(
    data1,data2,
    on = 'title',
    how ='left'
)
```

But it‘s memory expensive.
The size of data1 is (2942087, 7)(or some time maybe more than 3 times of the row numbers) and the size of data2 is (47516640, 4)
My memory size is 32GB, but it‘s not enough
I also try to use `polars`
In `polars` :

```py
dataall = data1.join(
    data2,
    on = 'title',
    how ='left'
)
```

A error occurs

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
```

I have tried the function `is_in` in `polars` and encoding the text to number, they are fast but I don't know how to realize.
Is there an efficiency and feasible way by pandas/polars/numpy?

After the suggestion by @ritchie46
-----edit 2022-5-24 16:00:10

```py
import polars as pl
pl.Config.set_global_string_cache()

data1 = pl.read_parquet('data1.parquet.gzip').lazy()
data2 = pl.read_parquet('data2.parquet.gzip').lazy()

data1 = data1.with_column(pl.col('source_post_title').cast(pl.Categorical))
data2 = data2.with_column(pl.col('source_post_title').cast(pl.Categorical))


dataall = data1.join(
    data2,
    on = 'source_post_title',
    how ='left'
).collect()
```

It seems that the code works for a period of time and then

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Is this because my processor itself is too weak?
My CPU is `i7-10850H`

Comment: Have you tried [dask merge](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge.html)?

Comment: How many duplicates do you have for each title? You can try to convert to factor/categorical to save space.

Comment: I am not familiar with dask, is it memory friendly? @Steven

Comment: Even though I hvae tried to convert data to categorical type in pandas , my memory is not enough. @mozway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot duplicate in your join keys, the output table might be a lot larger than any of the tables you are joining on.

Things that might help in `polars` are:

- Using `Categorical` datatype, so that duplicates are cached.
- Deduplicate your join keys, so that the output table does not explode (if it is allowed for correctness).
- Use polars lazy API directly from the `scan` level. That way intermediate results are cleared and won't maintain in RAM. Besides that, the polars might do other optimizations that reduce memory pressure.

If you don't need all output data, but let's say only the first x million rows of the join result, you can use polars lazy.

```py
lf_a = pl.scan_parquet("data1")
lf_a = # some more work

lf_b = p.scan_parquet("data2"_
lf_b = # some more work

# take only first million rows
N = int(1e6)

# because of the head operation the join will not materialize a full output table
lf_a.join(lf_b).head(N)
```

Comment: After the suggestion I try with the updated code in the question, but still a the same  error occurs.

Comment: Can you take the discussion to github and produce an example to reproduce your error?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't have full ownership of this data. `merge` or `join` is not an appropriate way to do this, I tried to use a for loop to do this a little bit. @ritchie46